# Get Dockerfile of a bioconda package

Tags: rstudio, bioconda, docker

Bioconda packages have associated containers images. E.g. `bioconductor-csaw` has the image `quay.io/biocontainers/bioconductor-csaw`.

I would like to customize the image, in particular, I would like to add rstudio.

It is possible to get the Dockerfile associated to the image of a bioconda package?

How do you suggest to proceed to customize the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dockerfile is generated by galaxy-utils, so I'm not entirely sure what it looks like. However you should be able to generate such a "mulled" container as documented [here](https://github.com/BioContainers/mulled). In short, something of the form:

```
mulled-build build 'bioconductor-csaw=someversion--somebuildnumber' 'someotherpackage=someversion--somebuildnumber' ...
```

That probably requires setting the CONDA_IMAGE environment variable. Bioconda currently sets that to `quay.io/dpryan79/mulled_container:latest`.